# How to track groups of customers in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

On our site, each of our customers are assigned to a customer group, and based on that customer group they have access to different web pages and products. What we'd like to do is track activity and revenue for each of those customer groups in Google Analytics 4. If possible, how would we achieve this?

Would it require setting up Content Groups, or possibly User-ID's using a data layer that passes the userId along with the customerGroup?

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
  'event' : 'login',
  'userId' : '[userId]',
  'customerGroup' : '[customerGroup]'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already passing the data to the data layer, then you can access it easily with a data layer variable. In the `Data Layer Variable Name` field, just enter `customerGroup` and it will now be passed to GTM for use.

If you are setting up a custom push, you need to make sure the push happens after the gtm snippet is loaded. If not, I believe it won't take (either there isn't a data layer to push to, or it will be overwritten once gtm loads).

For the user and/or event you want the data, make sure to pass the variable in a parameter within the tag and setup the custom dimension on the GA4 side. In my experience, the parameter won't be available in GA4 until a day later (or whenever you next refresh occurs). So there will be some wait time until you can create it.